# set scalable background image to svg image in fabric js

Tags: image, canvas, svg, background, scale

I am working with fabric js for designing, I have svg image with different shapes like circle, square. Now I have to apply background image to svg. But user can scale that image so that only required part of image will be set as background.
Please check attached. I have circle image with svg, and cupcake as background.

[Background Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LsST.jpg)

[Right now upload png but I have same svg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFrpo.png)

Now lets say I want only frosting part as background so I want to scale background image. Is this possible?

```
setPattern: function(currentElement,url,width,left_offset,top_offset,angle,padding,isrepeat){ 

        if(width === "undefined" || width == 100) { width = 100; } else { width = width ;} 
        if(left_offset === "undefined" || !left_offset){ left_offset = 0; } else { left_offset = left_offset } ;//left_offset;
        if(top_offset === "undefined" || !top_offset) { top_offset = 0; } else { top_offset = top_offset; }//top_offset;
        if(angle === "undefined" || !angle) { angle = 0; } else{ angle = angle; }
        if(padding === "undefined" || !padding){ padding = 0; } else {padding = padding;}
        if(!isrepeat){ isrepeat = 'no-repeat'; }

        fabric.Image.fromURL(url,function(img){
            img.scaleToWidth(width);
            //if (angle > 0) img.set('angle', angle);
            //if(padding > 0) padding = (padding,10);
            var patternSourceCanvas = new fabric.StaticCanvas();
            patternSourceCanvas.add(img);
            patternSourceCanvas.renderAll();
            var pattern = new fabric.Pattern({
                source: function() {
                    patternSourceCanvas.setDimensions({
                        width:img.getWidth() + padding,
                        height:img.getHeight() + padding
                    });
                    patternSourceCanvas.renderAll();
                    return patternSourceCanvas.getElement();
                },
                repeat: isrepeat,
                src: url,
            });

            if(left_offset > 0) { pattern.offsetX = (left_offset, 10); } else{ pattern.offsetX = 0;}
            if(top_offset > 0) { pattern.offsetY = (top_offset, 10); } else { pattern.offsetY = 0;}
            currentElement.paths[0].setFill(pattern);
            //currentElement.bringToFront();
            canvas.renderAll();
        });
    }
```

Comment: ok so user can change the background Image & scale it too...am i correct ?

Comment: yes, user will upload image and scale it

Comment: for that we need to see your code...something like setBackgroundImage

Comment: right now I am using set Pattern, I didn't found code for set Background image for object, it is directly for canvas. Please check question I have update it with code for set pattern.